# Flutter draggable widget -child is always created while dragging

Tags: flutter, draggable

Im trying to implement draggable widget in my flutter app. ImageWidget is a statefulWidget which i want to put inside the draggable. I have set same imageWidget object as both child and feedback of the Draggable widget. When I drag the draggable widget, ImageWidget's build method is being called always. How can I prevent this?

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  Offset position = Offset(0, 0);
  Widget _image;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _image = ImageWidget();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: new Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Drag Image"),
        ),
        body: Container(
            child: Stack(
          children: [
            Positioned(
              top: position.dy,
              left: position.dx,
              child: Draggable(
                maxSimultaneousDrags: 1,
                child: _image,
                feedback: _image,
                childWhenDragging: Container(),
                onDragStarted: () {},
                onDragEnd: (DraggableDetails details) {
                  setState(() {
                    position =
                        Offset(details.offset.dx, details.offset.dy);
                  });
                },
              ),
            )
          ],
        )),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ImageWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ImageWidgetState createState() => _ImageWidgetState();
}

class _ImageWidgetState extends State<ImageWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("Inside the build method of ImageWidget");
    return Image.network(
        "https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/beautiful-water-drop-on-dandelion-260nw-789676552.jpg",
        width: 200,
        height: 200,);
  }
}
```

Comment: The `build` method may be called at any time to rebuild your widget. You can't control that. Especially if the parent Widget gets rebuilt. Why don't you want that method to be called?